# Using HTML5 on nodejs and Images

Tags: javascript, image, html, node.js, collision

Is it possible to load an image data using nodejs server ? My main purpose is to code a pixel-perfect 2d collision and it sure must be server-side. I want to learn if I can load images and split it into pixels (actually, pixel array) on nodejs like in html5. If It is not possible, can I get some ideas to make a pixel-perfect collision at server-side ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you speak of HTML5 I presume you want to use `<canvas/>` or something similar. For that tag you can use the server side implementation of canvas: [canvas api for nodejs](http://ajaxorg.posterous.com/canvas-api-for-nodejs)